# Is it possible to play two different sounds through two sound cards at the same time?

Tags: sound-card, playback

Is it possible to play two different sounds through two sound cards at the same time?  For example: Media Player audio through sound card one and GOM Player through sound card two at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

As other have already mentioned, media players normally have the option to use the default audio device or any other in its preferences settings.

If you are using Vista or Windows 7, you can also set a secondary audio device to be the default communication device (look in Sound Properties), so you can have normal sound coming out of your speakers, but have Skype calls coming in through your headset, for example.

[image: Sound Properties]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Simply tell the two programs to use different sound cards in their configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Also some Applications can direct game sounds to SoundCard A while chat to Soundcard B,  WOW does this.   I **Belive** in windows, if you start an application then change the default soundcard then start a different application they will play out different sound cards.